# Rails: Catch a request in a scope when the request doesn't match anything in the scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Let's take the following router  :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ":locale", locale: /en|nl/ do
    get "/:slug", to: "pages#prefixed_action", constraints: { slug: /.*/ }
  end

  root to: "pages#simple_action"
  get "/:slug", to: "pages#simple_action", constraints: { slug: /.*/ }
end
```

If the request specifies a locale, the scope catches it and forwards it to `pages#prefixed_action`. If not the request is forwarded to`pages#simple_action`.

My issue is that if I enter `localhost:3000/en` in the browser, it won't be catched by the scope. How can I arrange that ?

Edit1: I'd like the request to be routed to "pages#prefixed_action"

Edit2: added a `root` declaration in the code sample

Comment: In addition to @maicher's great answer below, I believe the `constraints: { slug: /.*/ }` clause is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possibilities is to specify `root` inside the scope:

```
scope ":locale", locale: /en|nl/ do
  root 'pages#prefixed_action'
  get "/:slug", to: "pages#prefixed_action", constraints: { slug: /.*/ }
end
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not precise enough. There is already a `root` declaration outside the scope. So adding `/admin/cms/block_contents/42537/edit` inside the scope creates an error `ArgumentError at /
Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' `

Comment: Then you can just use `get '/' => ...`, you don't *need* the "root" method.

Comment: The root reffers to the scope. So it doesn't matter that you already have one root outside the scope. The error happens, because both (root and get inside the scope) points to the same controller action `pages#prefixed_action`. Specify another action for root. eg: `root 'pages#index'` (also create method `index` inside `PagesController`).

Comment: Thanks but adding another action isn't what I'm looking for. I want a `/en` request to be sent to "pages#prefixed_action".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply like this:

```
get '/:locale', to: "pages#prefixed_action", constraints: { locale: /(en|nl)/ }
get '/:locale', to: "pages#simple_action", constraints: { locale: /.*/ }
```

If your goal is to send to `pages#prefixed_action` with paths `/en` and `/nl` and all other to `pages#simple_action`. If so, put

```
get '/:locale', to: "pages#simple_action", constraints: { locale: /.*/ }
```

As a last route in your routes